# Spring boot 3 and springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui missing path variable inputs

Tags: spring, openapi, swagger-ui, spring-boot-3

I'm doing an exercise with Spring Boot to check version changes.
I have created a simple API and implemented spring swagger for API testing.
What is missing are the variable path parameters that do not appear in the swagger interface to enter the values.
According to the documentation, it is only necessary to define the RestController class and Maven dependency and test it, but that is not the case.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerRestController {
    
    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    
    @GetMapping()
    public List<Customer> customers() {
        return customerRepository.findAll();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Customer get(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return customerRepository.findById(id).orElse(new Customer());
    }
    
}
```

I try with 2.1.0, 2.2.0 and 2.3.0. same result.

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
     <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

[image]

The project structure is complex, but after compiling the entire paymentchain-parent project you can run the independent customer project and see the result by accessing the url *http://localhost:8081/swagger.html*

https://github.com/argades/spring-boot-ms-test

Comment: Can you push your sample code into git and share the link here? with the given info it should work, so I just wanted to check the whole code

Comment: @kcsurapaneni, I added more info

Comment: This seems to be linked to spring boot 3.2.x with 3.1.x it works just fine. I've noticed that with spring 3.2.x annotations relying on name being picked up from name of field doesn't work without explicitly specifying name

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution.
Adding this **("id")** to PathVariable annotation, show the input into ui

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public Customer get(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
     return customerRepository.findById(id).orElse(new Customer());
}
```

Thanks

Comment: surprisingly I had the same problem after I've added `suspend` to my controller running on Spring Boot 3 and using WebMVC -- all parameters disappeared from Open API spec. Adding name to the PathVariable annotation fixed the problem. I have no idea why but thanks 